# Chrome not re-applying floats after media queries

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I'm trying to create a 3-box column layout for my website. I also want these 3 boxes to collapse once the browser window gets to less than 700px wide. I've ended up using a combination of divs and some floats, and have been able to get it to work in all browsers except Chrome.

When you first load it in Chrome, it seems to work - there are three floating boxes in the correct places. Once you resize your browser, though, it messes with the rightmost two boxes. This does not happen in IE or Firefox.

Full screen, correct box layouts:
[image: Full screen, correct box layouts.]

<700px correct layout:

[image: <700px correct layout]

After resizing back to full screen:
[image: Incorrect layout after resizing]

It seems to me that Chrome isn't re-applying one of the floats (or another property) after the browser resizes back to >700px. Is there any reason for this, or is it a bug?

Code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/omfAj

HTML:

```
<div class="bubbles">
    <div class="bubble">
    </div>

    <div class="bubble">
    </div>

    <div class="bubble">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.bubbles {
    text-align: center; /* centers the middle bubble */
}
    .bubbles .bubble {
        width: 25%;
        height: 300px;

        border: 1px solid black;
    }
        .bubbles .bubble:nth-child(1) {
            float: left;
        }
        .bubbles .bubble:nth-child(2) {
            display: inline-block; /* this is basically a replacement for float:center, it'll cause it to position based on the text-align:center in .bubbles */
        }
        .bubbles .bubble:nth-child(3) {
            float: right;
        }


@media all and (max-width:700px) {
    .bubbles .bubble:nth-child(1),
    .bubbles .bubble:nth-child(2),
    .bubbles .bubble:nth-child(3) {
        float: none;
        display: block;
        width: 70%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        margin-top: 50px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**DEMO: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oJnhc**

This is the bug here (it's likely the first one):
https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=53166
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=329611

```
.bubbles {
    text-align: center; /* centers the middle bubble */
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
.bubbles .bubble {
    width: 25%;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.bubbles .bubble:nth-child(1) {
    float: left
}
.bubbles .bubble:nth-child(2) {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
}
.bubbles .bubble:nth-child(3) {
    float: right
}
@media all and (max-width:700px) { 
    .bubbles {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .bubbles .bubble,
    .bubbles .bubble:nth-child(1),
    .bubbles .bubble:nth-child(2),
    .bubbles .bubble:nth-child(3) {
        float: none;
        display: block;
        width: 70%;
        margin: 50px auto 0;
        left: 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much :D I've been banging my head around trying to google this for quite a while, this just made my day :)

Comment: Oops, spoke too soon :\ It seems like this works by not applying the float:none to :nth-child(3), so it still floats right. See: https://i.imgur.com/nPGaQ8Q.png

Comment: any idea how to fix this?

Comment: The only way to get this layout since the bug fix has not happened for more than a year is this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/IBtrp